# Leaflet: Use dynamic filters in GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, leaflet, geojson

I've got this pretty close but I'm struggling to understand how to pass multiple user submitted form checkbox values through to the Leaflet geoJSON filter function and only display those points.

[image: user checkboxes]

What I have so far...

```
$('#map-filters').on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    map.spin(true,spinOpts);
    submittedValues = $(this).serializeArray();
    var filteredLocations = L.markerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true }),
        filteredLocationsAjax = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(Routes.filtered_locations_path({format: 'json'}), {
          style: style,
          pointToLayer: pointToLayer,
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
          filter: function(feature, layer) {
            if(submittedValues.length <= 1) {
              return feature.properties[submittedValues[0].value];
            } else {
              How do I return multiple values?
            }
          }
        });
    filteredLocationsAjax.on('data:loaded', function () {
      map.removeLayer(allLocations);
      filteredLocations.addLayer(filteredLocationsAjax);
      map.addLayer(filteredLocations);
      map.spin(false);
    });
  });
```

And an example of my geoJSON...

```
{
  type: "Feature",
  geometry: {
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [
    "-76.286955",
    "45.335969"
  ]
},
  properties: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mississippi River",
    body_of_water: null,
    url: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/locations/2",
    observations_count: 1,
    ph: true,
    water_temperature: true,
    oxygen: true,
    phosphates_threshold: true,
    clarity: true,
    nitrites: true,
    nitrates: true,
    issues_count: 3,
    water_quality: true,
    algae: true
  }
}
```

This works fine if the user has only submitted one checkbox, the map filters exactly how I want. But how would I pass multiple values to this?

I've seen people suggest using...

`return (feature.properties[value] && feature.properties[value])`

But how would I pass multiple values into a return statement like that, as the user could select 1 or 20 checkboxes.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207327/leaflet-use-dynamic-filters-in-geojson-layer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should just loop through all your `submittedValues` array items and perform your test.

E.g. you could use [`submittedValues.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test that every checked box value is `true` for the given `feature`:

```js
filter: function (feature, layer) {
  return submittedValues.every(function (element) {
    return feature.properties[element.value];
  });
}
```

Of course you could do exactly the same with a classic `for` loop:

```js
filter: function (feature, layer) {
  for (var i = 0; i < submittedValues.length; i += 1) {
    if (!feature.properties[submittedValues[i].value]) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think I had looked at this for far to long and overlooked that route. Thank you! :)

Comment: Happens to everyone… thank you for the feedback! :-)