# Leaflet layer controls for array properties mess up results, how to fix? better solution for large amounts of geoJSON data and several filters?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, filtering

My end goal is to show a map with several hundred markers, each containing some information in a popup. Those markers are fairly close and some are in the very same spot, so they should be clustered and must be separately clickable for the popup. I also want to be able to filter them by several properties, starting with two array properties (phases and tags).

I actually managed to set all of that up quite nicely by using the MarkerCluster and MarkerCluster-LayerSupport plugins. I have 19 different tags and 4 different phases with corresponding FeatureGroups, all the markers are added to the respective groups, and there are two controls with checkboxes on the map. [You can check it out here if you like.](https://map.netzhexe.de/)

However, these controls act a little weirdly, or rather, not quite the way I'd like them to. All markers are on at least two layers, so when I uncheck "Tag #2", the FeatureGroup with all the markers with tag #2 is removed. That includes markers with tag #3 and tag #6, which are still checked and which therefore I'd like to keep on the map… so when you check and uncheck boxes in both controls, the results become quite unpredictable.

Is there a way to fix this, by somehow reevaluating all the checked layers? Or should I go a completely different route with the filtering? [For example this seems to be a jQuery filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000727/leaflet-use-dynamic-filters-in-geojson-layer). I find it hard to gauge performance issues though – I'm importing all the data into a separate geoJSON file with PHP, and I expect to get several hundred markers at some point, possibly more. I'm fairly new to Leaflet and handling large amounts of data in JS.

I will of course post my code if you'd like to see it, but since it's all working as intended and it's quite a lot, I'm not sure it's useful at this point.

Any pointers, ideas and best practice tips are most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have worked a little with Leaflet. In my experience, you need to have in mind that you need to group the common markers in a single layer, but the geo-JSON files put all markers in a single layer, no matter with properties has.

I did something similar to you, but I preprocessed all added markers to group them by specific properties. It is good because it can give you more control and do whatever you need, but that needs more initial time to preprocess all the info (and more if you are planning to have thousands of markers).

To check and manage all possible points you can use the `pointToLayer` method in the geoJSON loading:

```
  const tagCategories = {};
  .
  .
  .
  L.geoJSON(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      const tagName = feature.properties.tagName;
      const marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
      if (!tagCategories[tagName]) {
        tagCategories[tagName] = [];
      }
      tagCategories[tagName].push({marker, feature});
      return marker;
    }
  }).addTo(map);
  .
  .
  .

  function myFilterFunction({feature}) {
    return feature.properties.year === '1981';
  }

  document.querySelector('.tag1Btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const places = tagCategories[tagName].filter(myFilterFunction);
    // Do whatever you need with places.

  })
```

My best advice is to try to use vanilla js to reduce the overhead of preprocessing because libraries like `jQuery`, `lodash` and `underscore` do the same and in some cases are fast, but generally, Vanilla JS is faster if is used properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't see how that solves my problem. Like I said, all the markers are grouped nicely on different layers, but they all are on several layers at once. So deselecting the first two phases of the four removes all markers (check it out if you like), which is not the behaviour I'd expect as a user.